# In Firebug's HTML view, is there a way to inspect the underlying Dijit object of a widget's DOM node?

Tags: firebug, dojo

That is, by selecting an HTML element that would be a Dijit's containerNode, being able to inspect that Dijit's properties. Sort of a poor man's substitute for the old DojoFireBugExtension's widget view.

Or, assuming there's no appropriate break point, a work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually copy the ID (generated or selfmade) and paste the following in my console:

```
dijit.byId("my_id");
```